# How to properly test an application with cordova-plugin-purchase with capacitor?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have question, how to properly test an application with cordova-plugin-purchase with capacitor?

I did all the steps uploaded aab in Google Play Console in closed testing, added testers, added products and activated them. And now the question, I have to always upload a new version in Google Play Console to test and wait 2 hours for the app to be reviewed? Or is there some other method to test locally?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload your aab to the internal testing section within google play store. It doesn't take 2 hours for it approved. It's instant.

Comment: Is this the only way to test this functionality?

Comment: No, you can also run the app in debug mode through a physical device. Check out the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/debugging